# remove unneccesarry path transveral in unix path by regex which create with . and

Tags: java, regex

this path `(str = /tmp/a/b/12-3/ab-c/1-23/../../real/env.sh)` have unnesarry `/ab-c/1-23/../..` i like to remove this in by regex in java . I tried multiple regex pattern but it not working .

Comment: `I tried multiple regex` ... please include your attempted Java code, and also show us clear input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to consider that regex is a solution for all string problems. In your case, it is better to use [`getCanonicalPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) of the [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class:

```java
String path = "/tmp/a/b/12-3/ab-c/1-23/../../real/env.sh";
String canonical = new File(path).getCanonicalPath();
// "/tmp/a/b/12-3/real/env.sh"
System.out.println(canonical);
```

But just to show you, here a possible way by using regex:

```java
String path = "/tmp/a/b/12-3/ab-c/1-23/../../real/env.sh";
while (path.matches("^.*\\/\\.{2}.*$")) {
    path = path.replaceFirst("\\/[\\w-]+\\/\\.{2}", "");
}
// "/tmp/a/b/12-3/real/env.sh"
System.out.println(path);
```

Comment: Thanks for informing canonicalPath , this is better